Sens d'une image : « autant de tarauds dans le fût des secrets » ; Molloy, Samuel Beckett
Tiré de Molloy, Samuel Beckett

Ainsi mis je ne pouvais guère espérer passer inaperçu. Je ne le
désirais pas. Se faire remarquer, dans le métier que je faisais, c’est
l’enfance de l’art. Faire naître des sentiments de pitié, d’indulgence,
provoquer l’hilarité et les sarcasmes, c’est indispensable. Autant de tarauds dans le fût des secrets. À condition de ne pouvoir
s’émouvoir, ni dénigrer, ni rire. Je me mettais facilement dans cet
état.

Des tarauds sont des outils qui servent à faire des filetage ou forer des trous. (TLFi)
Le rapprochement de ces outils avec des fûts n'est pas clair du tout ; est-ce que quelqu'un saurait de quoi il s'agit ? Que sont ces tarauds imagés ?

La deuxième défintion colle mieux, à mon avis.

L'auteur fait allusion au taraudage¹ des fûts de bière. Cette opération permet l'aération. Tarauder c'est faire un trou, percer.
Je comprends l'image ainsi : « Faire naître des sentiments de pitié, d’indulgence, provoquer l’hilarité et les sarcasmes » aide à percer la carapace (→le fût) derrière laquelle on cache ses secrets.
Pour information la version anglaise :

To call forth feelings of pity and indulgence, to be the butt of jeers and hilarity, is indispensable. So many vent-holes in the cask of secrets.

On constate que Beckett a vraiment gardé la même image.

 ¹ On pourra rechercher « taraudage d'un fût de bière » ou « aérateur d'un fût de bière » sur internet. Comme ça renvoie à des sites commerciaux je ne fais pas de liens. 

C'est une interprétation satisfaisante, probablement la seule.

+1 pour le recours à la traduction anglaise: j'en étais à supposer un arbre dont le fût contînt les secrets.

@FrançoisJurain J'espère que c'est clair que ce n'est pas ma traduction ? Beckett a d'abord écrit en français puis en anglais. Je l'ai déjà écrit quelque part mais je ne sais plus à propos de quelle question...;-)  C'est toi le close ? Franchement si on ne connait pas le processus d'aération de la bière, c'est pas évident à comprendre. Oui, d'accord on n'est pas sur homebrewing, mais bon...

Ben non j'ai voté contre ce VTC. La raison donnée en était "opinion-based". Quelle opinion??????????????????????? que c'est-t-eske je me dis. C'est d'autant moins compréhensible que le VTC est arrivé après ta réponse. Au vu d'icelle, ça se voit bien que tu as découvert la seule interprétation possible, yapa d'opinion à avoir.

@FrançoisJurain Entièrement d'accord. Encore un exemple que les votes ne sont pas toujours fiables.
